# Drag 'n drop not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple drag 'n drop function in my website to select a file. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-selecting-files-dnd) to implement it. I copied and pasted the code, and it doesn't work.

I tried it on chrome and internet explorer, and they both had the same results, i.e. it would bring up a new page with the image. I want it to get the file path just like when you upload it from a regular `input type="file"`.

I then tried it on a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4envas9d/), and it works in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4envas9d/). How can I get it to work in my browser? Here's a [link to the files](http://jmp.sh/vZgaat8).

Code snippet:

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();

  var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
      f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
      f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
      '</li>');
  }
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

function handleDragOver(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
}

// Setup the dnd listeners.
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.example {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
#drop_zone {
  border: 2px dashed #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 20pt bold'Vollkorn';
  color: #bbb;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
  <output id="list"></output>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you running these files directly in the browser (e.g. file://some_dir/test.html) or are you hosting them first?

Comment: I'm using bracket, which has live preview. I tried it with that, and it didn't work. I then tried it directly in the browser and it didn't work either.

Comment: `Ctrl-Shift-I` in Chrome to bring up dev-tools and go to console panel and look for errors. Your snippet runs fine for me.

Comment: The snippet runs fine, but if you download the files, it won't.

Comment: Then Nick has the answer for you. jsFiddle will "properly" order things for you. This `var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');` is null because `document.getElementById('drop_zone');` doesn't exist when you query for it. Scripts are executed in the order encountered in the document parse phase.

Comment: In dev tools you can `console.log(dropZone);` to see this for yourself. Tho you should have been getting an error there anyway since `undefined.addEventListener....` should have been failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your script is being executed before the DOM loads. The simplest fix would be to move the `<script>` tag referencing `filedrag.js` to the bottom of `body`.

If you want to keep `filedrag.js` in your document head, you need to wait until the DOM is fully loaded before trying to reference an element such as `drop_zone`. Since you decided to use jQuery, here's how you might do it:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
        f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
        f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
            '</li>');
    }
    $('#list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

function handleDragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
}

// This is necessary or jQuery won't include the data property when an event is triggered
// It's recommended you use the native event listeners, as this method will add extra overhead.
$.event.props.push("dataTransfer");

// Setup the dnd listeners.
window.onload = function(e) {
    var dropZone = $('#drop_zone');
    dropZone.on('dragover', handleDragOver);
    dropZone.on('drop', handleFileSelect);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just figured another way. If I insert in the js file: `$(document).ready(function()` Then it doesn't matter where I insert the `script` tag. The reason is the same logic you wrote. Since I'm inserting the `$(document).ready(function()`, I want it to all be JQuery, Can you please convert that to JQuery?

Comment: @Jessica Sure, I'll do that in an hour or so. I'm about to head home right now

Comment: @Jessica Sorry it took so long to get back to you! I just updated the post. The change is very minor, but as you can see none of the code will be executed until jQuery's `$(document).ready(..)` event fires. If you wanted, you could put all your code in the `.ready()` callback, but you would be constrained by the scope of that single function.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant was, can you please convert the whole code to jquery.

Comment: Thanks! Also the addEventListener. Is there a way to do that in JQuery?

Comment: @Jessica You really, really don't need to use jQuery, but have you even tried googling this?

Comment: Yes. This is what I got, `var dropZone = $('#browseFileDiv');

    dropZone.on('dragover', handleDragOver());
    dropZone.on('drop', handleFileSelect());` which is wrong.

Comment: @Jessica I updated my answer. Truthfully, I had no idea why it wasn't working until I found http://stackoverflow.com/a/14792183/1146881

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna up-vote the answer. I probably should have asked a new question. Thanks!

Comment: @Jessica Glad I could help! And nah, I don't think you should've asked a new question. I said I would update my answer to use jQuery but I didn't quite finish the job the first time around, so thanks for pointing out what I missed. edit: also I just noticed someone down-voted your question, not really sure why.